# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded

Tags: angular, angular-cli, aot, angular-compiler

I'm trying to use AOT compilation using ng build --prod. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Project Url- https://github.com/nishant1596/sampleAOT

Please Help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was using this form of lazyLoading -

```
loadChildren : ()=> import ('./home/home.module').then(m=>m.HomeModule)
```

instead of

`loadChildren : './home/home.module#HomeModule`'